# Angularjs - $location.path with slashes in url

Tags: angularjs, url, path, angular-ui-router, slash

it's possible to specify to $location.search to send parameters with slashes in url ?

Here is my state:

```
.state('home/room', {
                url: '/:home_id/:room_id',
                templateUrl: 'home/layout.html'
            });
```

Using links it works perfectly:

```
<a ui-sref="home/room({home_id:20, folder_id: 608})"> // I get url: "/20/608"
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with $location.path ?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$location.path("home/room({home_id:20, room_id: 608})")

$location.search({home_id: 20, room_id: 608});
```

I get `/?home_id=20&room_id=608`

But I would like `/20/608`

I'm trying to avoid using regex. Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are using is specific to angular-ui-router. To get the URL to be correct using `$location` you can do string concatenation to build the URL.

```
$location.path("home/room"+homeId+"/"+roomId);
```

It is recommended use the angular-ui-router function of `$state.go()` to transistion between states when using angular-ui-router and `$stateProvider`

```
$state.go('home/room',{home_id:20, folder_id: 608});
```

Comment: see also: ui-sref directive